# Certificates not accessible while there are no active logins on webserver

Tags: certificate, asp.net, iis-7.5, mvc

My mvc application uses a certificate (stored in the Local Computer's 'Root Certification Authority' store), but cannot seem to access it while the web-server doesn't have any active users logged in [to the machine].

This causes a service failure when a user is logged in to the web application.

```
<clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"  509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="certificate name" />
```

I was worried it might be permissions or something, but in development the boxes tended to remain online and we never encountered the issue.

Any help is appreciated, thank-you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the solution to my problem. However, I'm not sure why it works. Through experimentation I was able to find that IIS would not attempt to read certs from any store location except for "LocalMachine" and any store name except for "Personal".

It took me a while to come to this conclusion and I tried most combinations of [storeLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation.aspx) and various [storeNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx).

If anybody knew why it is that the Root Certificate store is inaccessible to IIS, that would be interesting to learn.

Thanks!